# Change color in imager and save image

Tags: r, save, imager

The documentation of `imager` shows how to specify your own colors in a plot (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imager/vignettes/gettingstarted.html)). This is super handy but I seem to be unable to save a modified plot. How can I achieve that?

```
library(imager); library(dplyr)
cscale <- function(r, g, b) rgb(g, r, b)
plot(boats, colourscale=cscale, rescale=FALSE)
```

This works fine. But how can I save this plot? This does not work:

```
boats %>%
  plot(colourscale=cscale, rescale=FALSE) %>%
  save.image("pathtomachine.jpg")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the base pipeline of choosing a device and closing it.

```
> library(imager)
> cscale <- function(r, g, b) rgb(g, r, b)
> dims <- attributes(boats)$dim  ## get dims
> jpeg('foo.jpg', dims[1], dims[2])  ## open jpg device
> par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0))  ## switch off margins
> plot(boats, colourscale=cscale, rescale=FALSE)  ## plot
> dev.off() |> invisible()  ## close jpg device

> grep('foo.jpg', dir(), value=TRUE)  ## check if it's there
[1] "foo.jpg"
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the first approach is what does not work either (saves the original plot).

Comment: @Thomas Looks like a bug to me, contact the author. As workaround use base pipeline ad switch off the margins, see update.